# Copy text from a webpage

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos, keyword

Let's say we have a website speedywap.com

When I open the website in my browser and then I copy the page to the clipboard and when I paste it in my notepad (windows) only text remains. All the code is removed except for the text that was in links etc (i.e displayed on the screen).

I want to do something similar with php because I am trying to create a keyword density analyser. So I want something that is able to just keep the text from a webpage that is displayed on the screen.

My server is running apache, php, centos and mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://speedywap.com');
echo $content;
?>
```

you can use strip_tags to strip tags from it then you are just left with text.

Answer (score 2):

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    return curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}

$html = curl('http://speedywap.com');
```

cURL is many times faster then fgc.
You can use strip_tags but that doesnt guarantee anything, only way is to manually parse the page, using str_replace, preg_replace etc.

This is what you get using strip_tags :
http://pokit.etf.ba/get/47a07bd62ea42dd3d447f060c01ccfb5.png

Answer (score 2):

For a very naïve start, you can use this:

```
<?php

echo strip_tags(file_get_contents('http://speedywap.com'));

?>
```

Comment: I want only the text to remain... I know how to get the content and strip tags. What I am looking for is some code to remove all the html entities, tags, etc and then just keep the text as it is shown on the page(that includes dynamic content created by javascript, ajax, etc) But thanks for helping.

Comment: Getting the "displayed text" of arbitrary URLs as it appears after javascript has been executed is very, very difficult with raw PHP. I said "arbitrary URLs" because you must be talking about other websites also - the only difference I can see between speedywap.com with and without javascript is the adverts disappear without JS. However, if you are building a "keyword density analyser", you should not worry about content coming in through AJAX, as search engines cannot see it.

Comment: but there are websites such as facebook etc where this is critical content.

Comment: You need to make it more clear what you're trying to do; you need to expand on what you think a "keyword density analyser" is. If you want to "analyse" facebook pages (wall posts, comments), that's entirely different to doing it for arbitrary sites on the internet. Facebook has an [API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/), for instance.

Comment: To make this clear: if you are doing this from an SEO point of view, content which is behind AJAX is not relevant because search engines (Google) cannot see it (unless the site is using [this](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)).

Comment: google has started to consider the content produced through javascript and ajax

Comment: Its on official google blog. But what matters is helping me with the question.

Answer (score 1):

develop your code on this ->http://www.barattalo.it/2010/03/01/php-curl-bot-to-update-facebook-status/

Answer (score 0):

Use file_get_contents or curl if you want to get fancy.

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://speedywap.com');
echo $content; // or analyze, or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents('http://www.speedywap.com/');` to get the page source and then use some filters/regular expressions to get the text you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `strip_tags`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags` will not remove or replace things like the HTML space (`&nbsp;`), `&pound;`, `&ndash;`, etc. from the content like you need, as you say, a browser copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and paste into notepad. You will have to write specific code to replace each one like:

```
str_replace('& nbsp;',' ',$mytext); 
str_replace('& ndash;','-',$mytext);
```

etc. to handle these.
I needed to convert content created by users within `TinyMCE`, which allows formatting text, to plain text for a client. A PHP command that goes beyond `strip_tags` to do this would be great to have but I can't find one.

Comment: Thank you for editing Ramin eghbalian. I was unfamiliar with the system.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this to copy html from web page**

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://speedywap.com');
echo $html;
?>
```

**Try this to get a copy of webpage**

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://speedywap.com');
echo str_replace(
    '<head>', 
    '<head><base href="http://speedywap.com" target="_blank">',
     $html
 );
?>
```